# animations not working in android

Tags: android, animation

`imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));`

In the above line when I am using R.anim. **fade_in/fade_out/slide_in_left/slide_in_right** my app is working correctly. But if I am using any other animation, then in my phone it displays an error stopped unexpectedly. When I checked the error in the LogCat, it displayed an Runtime exception: Unknown animation name: cycleInterpolator (for example). Why is this happening

Comment: Did you write that animation in xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned four animations are built in for android. So, we dont need to write any special code for them. In the other case, they are not built in. So, you create a new folder in the res and name in anim. In the res/anim folder create a new xml file and write the animations for it using the tags

> **translate, scale, rotate, alpha, set**

Comment: These xml files(with the above tags-translate etc) with animations like shake,zoom_enter,zoom_exit are already available in the res.anim folder ...this is included in the android SDK. But I still get the Unknown animation name: cycleInterpolator error. Why's that?

Answer (score 1):

you can find the animations tutorial in this book: Android User Interface Development by Jason Morris